# Single or Multiple Model InJecting using service directive in seperate javascript file in angularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

When i am trying to inject single or multiple model using service directive in separate java script file , i am getting below error,But it si working in single Javascript files. Here customer is model

**Error:**

"Binding.js:33 Uncaught ReferenceError: Customer is not defined".
Binding.js:9 Uncaught ReferenceError: Customer is not defined(anonymous function) @ Binding.js:9
angular.js:13424 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: customerProvider <- customer <- myCustomerController

**Below is my code :**

**Model(customer.js) :**

```
     function Customer() {
       this.customerName = "David";
       this.customerCode = "C001";
      }
```

**Binding Code(Binding.js)**

```
    function BindingCode($scope,customer) {
    $scope.customer = customer;
    }
    var myCustomerApp = angular.module("myCustomerApp", []);
    myCustomerApp.controller("myCustomerController", BindingCode);
    myCustomerApp.service('customer', Customer);
```

View Code(customer.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/Binding.js"></script>
</head>


<body ng-app="myCustomerApp">
   <div ng-controller="myCustomerController">

    <table>

        <tr>
            <td>
                CustomerName
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type=text id="CustomerName" ng-model="customer.customerName" /><br />

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                CustomerCode
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type=text id="CustomerCode" ng-model="customer.customerCode" />

            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>

</div>
```

**But Same code is working  here only model and view and binding code included in section script in customer.html:**
**Model :Customer.js**

```
   function Customer() {
    this.customerName = "David";
    this.customerCode = "C001";
 }
```

**View code (customer.html)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
   <script src="Scripts/CustomerModle.js"></script>
  </head>

    <script>

    function BindingCode($scope, customer) {
        $scope.customer = customer;

    }
    var myCustomerApp = angular.module("myCustomerApp", []);
    myCustomerApp.controller("myCustomerController", BindingCode);
    myCustomerApp.service('customer', Customer);

</script>

<body ng-app="myCustomerApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCustomerController">
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is this related to Angular2?

Comment: have you include `customer.js` on page?

Comment: Where i should include it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should first inject the service into your controller before yousing that service.

```
BindingCode.$inject = ['Customer']
```

Re-arrange the **customer.js** into

```
var myCustomerApp = angular.module("myCustomerApp", []);
myCustomerApp.service('customer', Customer);
function Customer() {
   this.customerName = "David";
   this.customerCode = "C001";
  }
```

Rearrange the **Binding.js** into

```
var myCustomerApp = angular.module("myCustomerApp", []);
myCustomerApp.controller("myCustomerController", BindingCode);
BindingCode.$inject = ['Customer']

function BindingCode($scope,Customer) {
$scope.customer = Customer;
}
```

add `<script src="Scripts/customer.js"></script>` in your **customer.html** file

Comment: Please look at Binding Code , I have injected using below code :  myCustomerApp.service('customer', Customer);

Comment: It is not injecting, it is just using. You cant use an external service without injecting

myCustomerApp.service('customer', Customer); is assigning a name 'Customer' to a new service called 'customer'. its just initialising a service. It has no link to the controller

Comment: If i am moving binding.js code into customer.html within <script> </script> section , it works but if i move to seperate javascript files it' doesnot work.Also if i move model(customer.js)  code into binding.js ,again it works , then where is the injection problem myCustomerApp.service('customer', function Customer() {
    this.customerName = "David";
    this.customerCode = "C001";
}
);

Comment: Still i am getting Below Error :angular.js:13424 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: CustomerProvider <- Customer <- myCustomerController

Comment: Please check you have included customer.js script src in your index.html. And please keep either only 'customer' or 'Customer' everywhere. Please avoid playing with capitalization ;)

Comment: I am geting this error from Binding.js ,not from customer.html

Comment: Please take a look at this section :"But Same code is working here only model and view and binding code included in section script in customer.html: Model :Customer.js"

Comment: Yes I know. But the service customer is not getting in your Binding.js. That is the problem. So you have to create a customer.js file and have to add script src of that to your index.html. That is the only way to link your service and controller. Otherwise you need to write both service and controller functions in the same file

Comment: Do i need to both binding.js and customer.html or only to customer.html?

Comment: I cant understand why are yo talking about **customer.html** I'm talking about **customer.js**

You should include `<script src="Scripts/customer.js"></script>` in your **customer.html**

Comment: I need to add customer.js to customer.html ,correct

Comment: I am not able to understand here why i need to add reference of  model(customer.js) to view(customer.html) If i already have bind my model to binding code(binding.js) , binding attribute using in view(customer.html) to bind data from model to view.

Comment: The definition of the model(service) is in a different file. Even though you added it in the controller, the controller need to find the service definition. So you should include that definition file in **any of your html**

Comment: It's works. Thanks for suggestion . For better understanding i want to understand why we need to in any of html

Comment: If controller already know about model then why view should know about model ?

Comment: Then please accept the answer :) 

Actually html and javascript are totally different files. Like that two js files also. in your binding.js you are just calling the **customer**. but its definition is in another file. We can't connect to js files. So we are connecting those js files together and connecting to the html also through the script src. To avoid this **You have to write both service and controller code in the same file(in binding.js)**

Comment: i accepted it, i want to understand it , we are connecting those js files (binding.js and customer.js) files. can we connect binding.js and customer.js in itself in binding .js file

Comment: why view want to understand the model code, i think viewmodel(binding.js) should try to underdstand to model becuase we are using it in this

Comment: Lemme know then how the app get the definition of customer service??. If you are thinking we added that to controller. it's wrong.

Comment: There is an option under the downvote thing I think. (I've not asked any question yet. So i don't know ;) ) There will be tick mark. Click on that